# Prevent encoding of existing HTML entities (convert & to &amp; but not &amp; to &amp;amp;)

Tags: php, html, mysql

Data in my mysql database table has the special characters like '&'.

While using then I need to convert them to `&amp;`. I used the htmlspecialchars to convert them to HTML entities.

But few entry already has the `&amp;` and it converts them to `&amp;amp;` I need them to use as it is without conversion.

What to do?

Comment: This question is super confusing. You have data in the database that contains `&`, you are using `htmlspecialchars()` to turn those into HTML entities, but there are other entries in the database that have an `&` but you don't want those specific entries to have their `&` converted by `htmlspecialchars()` ???

Comment: You'll likely want to utilize a regex to accomplish this. Possibly something along the lines of `&(?!amp;)` should identify "naked" ampersands.

Comment: @ohgodwhy He has a mixture of data. Some safe for html, some not. He is asking to simply clean up naked ampersands, but not ampersands that are already escaped as `&amp;`

Comment: Thanks @Paul Crovella for editing the answer.

Comment: @PaulCrovella, yours is a good answer, why not post it as such?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best solution is to decode them first. Normal `&` will remain untouched, but `&amp;` is decoded to `&`.

Then encode them again to convert `&` and other special chars to their encoded equivalent. The code is shorter than the explanation. :)

```
$text = 'Your text with &amp;s from the database';
// Decode and re-encode the special characters.
$text = htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars_decode($text));
```

If you have other entities in there as well (like `&eacute;` for `é`),instead of `htmlspecialchars`, you can also use `htmlentities` and `html_entity_decode`. The solution is the same, but you can test which one yields the best result for you.

```
$text = 'Your text with &amp;s from the database';
// Decode and re-encode the special characters and other entities.
$text = htmlentities(html_entity_decode($text));
```

Both `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities` support the `doubleencode` parameter, which is true by default but can be set to false. This should prevent double encoding too. It sounds like that solution is even cleaner, but I haven't used it, and I don't know if it has any side effects.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to store pure text in the DB.

& stays &, é stays é, etc...

Only when reading from DB to 'assemble' HTML content I use htmlspecialchars().

This way I know that what is stored can be used anywhere regardless if it's html or text.